# How to make illumination moving effect on hover WINUI 3

Tags: windows, winui-3, glow

Sorry for maybe stupid question.
In WinUI 2 Gallery on reveal focus there is amazing effect on mouse over, is something like this in WinUI 3?[image: Effect example]

I tried to google, but it gives me nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinUI3, [RevealBackgroundBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.revealbackgroundbrush?view=winrt-22621) is no longer supported, and there is no related content in the [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.media?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2) Namespace.

In the document of `RevealBackgroundBrush`

> RevealBackgroundBrush is available for use in the operating systems
> specified in the Requirements section. However, we do not recommend
> its use as it may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions.

I think this should be the reason why `RevealBackgroundBrush` disappeared in WinUI3.